# SASS ampersand in each and parent rule set with new line(s)

Tags: sass

I have a special situation with each in rule sets.
So here is my example scss code. Seems to be ok for the style guide which says write unrelated rules in multi line.

```
$test: 'red' 'green';

.a,
.b {
  color: orange;
  @each $i in $test {
    .#{$i} & {
      color: #{$i};
    }
  }
}
```

I have the following generated css file:

```
.a,
.b {
  color: orange;
}
.red .a, .red
.b {
  color: red;
}
.green .a, .green
.b {
  color: green;
}
```

I don't like the new lines in the middle of my second selector in the css. Other hand, I don't want to write all the selector sets in one line in the scss to prepare to a future each injection. One line rule sets seems to be ok.

Ampersand seems to get the new line (\n) from the start of the second parent selector too.

How could I make both the scss and css looks pretty? How could I remove the new line char(s) from the ampersand?

EDIT: better example

Comment: If you don't like the newline, why do you have it in there?

Comment: "new lines **in the middle of** my second selector"

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried another [output style](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style)? You might like `expanded` style.

Comment: I just tried your sample code and I see the same result, it probably bug from the expanded output. You can ask on their official repo https://github.com/sass/sass/issues

Comment: I've reported that as a bug. Wait for the official reply.